# bash - how to process exit code when using set -e and get output of command

Tags: bash

I have `set -e` at top of script. How to avoid script termination for some commands and process exit code? I have a difficulty in following code sample:
I need both output to variable and exit code, without `set -e` its easy.

```
set -e
...
formoutput=$(yad --form --field="Subdomain" --field="Domain" --field="Web master username" \
  --field="Apache group" --field='Webroot' \
  --field='Webroot variables - ${homedir}(of webmaster) ${subdomain} ${webmaster} ${domain}:LBL' \
  --field="Virtualhost ip or domain" \
  --field="Virtualhost port" --field="Server admin email" \
  --field="Create mysql user&db:CHK" \
  --button="Cancel:3" --button="Save defaults:2" --button="Create:0" \
  --title="Create apache virtualhost" \
  --text='Subdomain are case sencetive for Webroot folder ${subdomain} variable' \
  --focus-field=1 --center --window-icon="preferences-system" --width=600 \
  "${config[subdomain]}" "${config[domain]}" "${config[webmaster]}" "${config[webgroup]}" \
  "${config[webroot]}" "test" "${config[virtualhost]}" "${config[virtualport]}" "${config[serveradmin]}" 1)
formbutton="$?"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to handle the exit code of the command.

The exit status of the command is the exit status of last command executed.

Variable assignment is not a command.

So you can just do what's popular in `set -e` scripts:

```
formoutput=$(yad ...) || ret=$? && ret=$?
```

to catch the return value.

Or you can ignore the exit by invoking `:` command:

```
formoutput=$(yad ...) ||:
```

The `||:` is really `||` with [`:`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/colon.html) command. The colon command returns exit status of zero, the exit status of the list of commands `a || b` is the exit status of the last command executed in the list, as `:` always returns zero, the list of commands will also return zero exit status.

Or use `if`:

```
if ! formoutput=$(yad ...); then 
          echo "AAAA! yad failed! abort ship!" >&2
fi
```

Note that `if` command also has an exit status of the last command executed. So be aware that:

```
if true; then
    false
fi
```

will exit from your `set -e` script.

Comment: With `if ! cmd` `$?`  is always `0`. I prefer `if cmd ; then :; else rc=$? ; fi`

Answer (score 4):

I needed to use the operators in the other order for this to work

```
$ set -e
$ true || status=$? && status=$?; echo $status
0
$ false || status=$? && status=$?; echo $status
0
$ true && status=$? || status=$?; echo $status
0
$ false && status=$? || status=$?; echo $status
1
```

Comment: Interesting the answer is actually wrong, `&&` should be first.

Comment: Yes, it seems the correct answer is with the `&&` first: `command && status=$? || status=$?`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
set -e
false || echo $? && echo 0
```

Even though `false` exits with 1, you'll be able to capture this exit value in the middle (with `$?`) without aborting the whole script.

If the script (`false`) didn't fail, the exit code is always zero so you can just put a zero on success.

Comment: This is how I do for other commands not in example code. Problem to capture output of a command and exit code, both.

Comment: ? it's just `formoutput=$(....) || echo $? && echo 0` The exit status of an expression is the return status of last command executed. Variable assignment is not command execution. So the exit status of `formoutput=$(bla)` will be the exit status of command `bla`.  And you can normally chain it. `if a=$(true); then echo 1; else echo 2; fi`

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks. I was stuck trying the similar but inside ()